# Check each position in the input entry and return the number of times a character occurs

Tags: java, string, loops, while-loop, char

I wrote the following code but I can't seem to convert the string to a char and then search the input entry string. My code is below. Any helpful tips would be greatly appreciated. I'm supposed to use a while loop but felt like for was easier to start with.

```
    public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
    String inputEntry;
    String inputCharacter;
    int length;
    int i;
    int counter = 0;

    System.out.println("Enter a string: ");
    inputEntry = in.next();
    System.out.println("Enter a letter: ");
    inputCharacter = in.next();

    length = inputCharacter.length();

    if (length == 1) {
        for(i = 0; i <= inputEntry.length(); i++){
            char c = inputCharacter.charAt(0);
            if (inputEntry.charAt(i) == c){
              counter++;
        }
        }
    }
    else {
        System.out.println("The input letter was not a single letter.");
    }

}
```

}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like the only problem in your code is that you are using `<=` instead of `<` within your loop. `<=` is incorrect because it passes string length as an index, but first character resides at `charAt(0)`, and last character resides at `charAt(inputEntry.length() - 1)`

Replacing your loop declaration with the following will do the trick:

```
for(i = 0; i < inputEntry.length(); i++){
```

Then you also need to `System.out.println(counter);` after the for loop.

Comment: Thank you! Fixed it up and works perfect. Except it won't let my string be more than one word. Am I missing something in: inputEntry = in.next();

Comment: @CoIH use `in.nextLine()` to read multiple words. If I helped you to solve a problem, please mark it as an answer ;)

Comment: Thank you so much!! Sorry, brand new to this...I will mark as an answer!